# Keep element inline with final line of previous element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently using a pseudo element to keep a difficulty tag inline with the page title when it spans multiple lines. However, this is being flagged by google since it's appearing as multiple h1 tags to their crawler -- which I guess makes sense. Is there a way to achieve this same effect while using an entirely separate element for the difficulty tag?

https://codepen.io/mrweiner/pen/XoGePG

```
<div class="container container--1">
  <h1>Here is a long title with a pseudo element tag</h1>
</div>

<div class="container container--2">
  <h1>Here's a multi-line title with a span tag</h1>
  <span class="difficulty">Beginner</span>
</div>

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 1em;

  h1 {
    max-width: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  &--1 h1::after {
    content: 'Beginner';
  }

  &--1 h1::after,
  .difficulty {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-style: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: .25rem;
    border: solid green 1px;
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Multiple `<h1>` tags is acceptable in HTML5. Change your DOCTYPE.

Comment: @PHPglue, you'd need to [separate them into individual sections](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824) to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply incorporate it into the heading:

```
<h1>Here's a multi-line title...<span class="difficulty">Beginner</span></h1>
```

[**Codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PXLONE)

If you'd rather not have the additional text in the heading, you might make the heading `inline`.

[**Codepen Demo 2**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXJamd)

Comment: I'd been trying to use the `display: inline` solution without any luck -- turns out my container was `display: flex` and screwing everything up. Whoops. Thanks for the sanity check!

Answer (score 0):

Check my updated fork using your pseudo element:

https://codepen.io/kirapwn/pen/LMaOEG

```
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
```

and `position:relative'

Comment: Thanks for taking a look but this doesn't address the issue. I'm currently using  the pseudo element, and like how that functions. What I need to do is mimic that with the separate element.

Comment: Why dont you put this H1 and .difficulty in the same div with position relative and do the same as I did for the pseudo element?

Answer (score 0):

add the tag to h1...

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 1em;
}
.container h1 {
  max-width: 350px;
  position: relative;
}
.container--1 h1::after {
  content: 'Beginner';
}
.container--1 h1::after,
.container .difficulty {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: .25rem;
  border: solid green 1px;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container--1">
  <h1>Here is a long title with a pseudo element tag</h1>
</div>

<div class="container container--2">
  <h1>Here is a long title with a pseudo element tag
  <span class="difficulty">Beginner</span>
  </h1>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You maybe missed where that was suggested (and rejected) in an earlier answer.

Comment: You may be right I tried the code I just saw a problem in some cases the text may be below the span